Use single arg to pass a list or two separate values in python function
How to use a single argument to pass multiple variables in Python function.
[code]
def f(*args):
    a, b, _ = args
    print(a, b)

f(10, 2)   # two separate values
f([10, 2]) # list

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Expected Output:
10 2

10 2


You have two values, but are trying to unpack 3. a, b, _ = args should be a, b = args.
If you want to pass a list directly, you'll need to remove the varargs f(*args) with a normal argument f(args).

flakes: For this case f(10, 2) - throwing TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given error.

Are you trying to change your function, to accept both of these calls? Or are you trying to change how you call your function? Or something else? It's not clear what the goal is.

I should have phrased that differently. The two ways of calling the method have semantic differences that don't play super nicely together. It is possible to write a method that accepts both ways, but that leads to confusing code and there are a few edge cases to consider or you'll have not so fun bugs. I would choose one style or the other, but not support both.

user2357112:  Need a single function which will accept the both cases at calling side. (without using much complex - e.g isinstance() etc.) I am looking for a solution of using "tuple unpacking concept - * "

@JaiK you can't really avoid something like isinstance or len(args), iterable unpacking doesn't really handle what you want. You could try pattern matching, which may be more maintainable but still verbose. In general, you want function arguments to be rigid, you want the caller to know what they are passing.

By far the best way to use unpacking would be at the call site: f(*whatever_list) rather than f(whatever_list). Trying to make the function itself handle a list or separate arguments is messy and bug-prone.

Keep in mind that unless you have a good reason to do so, forcing your functions to also accept a "single-arg list mode" argument will probably cause a design bug if you ever have a 1-argument function that expects a list, or list-of-lists. To get around this ambiguity, you can always do f(*[10,2]) to apply a function to a list, without having to special-case the first argument for everything function you define. Alternatively, you can just make sufficiently complicated functions take a single list/tuple. Alternatively, use keyword args and a decorator (but that looks and feels awkward).

You'll have to enforce certain rules that can help differentiate the two function signatures.
A good example would be the built-in max function, which takes items in form of either a single iterable or two or more arguments:
max(iterable, *, key=None)
max(arg1, arg2, *args, key=None)


If one positional argument is provided, it should be an iterable. The
largest item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional
arguments are provided, the largest of the positional arguments is
returned.

So you can use a similar rule, where the length of the variable arguments determines which signature the caller is using.
To type hint the different signatures you can use typing.overload:
from typing import overload, Iterable, Any

@overload
def f(iterable: Iterable): ...

@overload
def f(a: Any, b: Any): ...

def f(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        (a, b), = args
    else:
        a, b = args
    print(a, b)

f(10, 2)
f([10, 2])

This outputs:
10 2
10 2


Pylance warns that "Overloaded implementation is not consistent with signature of overload 1" for def f(*args). Can that be avoided?

Hmm interesting. I checked my code against mypy before posting. But if Pyright doesn't like it, perhaps we should file a bug against Pyright for it to allow *args to be compatible with any overloading signature.

@blhsing I think the issue is that def f(a: Any, b: Any): would mean that assigning by kwarg is okay. It should really be: def f(a: Any, b: Any, /):

def f(*args):
    if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], list):
        a, b, *_ = args[0]
    else:
        a, b, *_ = args
    print(a, b)

f(10, 2)   # two separate values
f([10, 2]) # list


For your second call the list passed in is considered as one argument so when you unpack the b also needs a value. Or you can have try except block to handle the error and the extra cases.
